# get() + sum() in one line laravel

Tags: php, laravel, get, sum

My data

```
invoice|amount|
0001   | 10000|
0001   | 10000|
```

Now my code on Controller;

```
$invoices = Invoice::where('user_id', 1)
    ->where('status', 'Paid')
    ->orderBy('datePaid', 'desc')
    ->groupBy('no_invoice')
    ->get()
    ->sum('amount');  return view('invoice', ['invoices' => $invoices]);
```

I want show all data with get() and sum only field amount like this on my foreach.

```
invoice|total amount|
0001   | 20000|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `selectRaw` in your select in query and then use `sum(amount)` like this

```
$invoices = Invoice::selectRaw('*, sum(amount) as total')
    ->where('user_id', 1)
    ->where('status', 'Paid')
    ->orderBy('datePaid', 'desc')
    ->groupBy('no_invoice')
    ->get();
```

Now you can print

```
foreach($invoices as $invoice){
     echo $invoice->total
}
```